# Take webcam picture from shell with minimal delay

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, webcam

I am looking for a command-line tool that can take a picture from a webcam **as fast as possible** and write it to stdout. In addition, I would like to be able to specify settings like input format, resolution and output format.

My first try was ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format yuyv422 -i /dev/video0 -f image2 -frames:v 1 -qscale:v 2 pipe:1
```

However, this has two drawbacks:

1. It takes about 3 seconds until the image is written to stdout, which seems to be due to the time the webcam needs to initialize.
2. The picture taken this way is rather dark, probably the webcam needs to capture a view video frames to adjust brightness etc..

My next idea is to continuously capture video frames from the webcam (i.e. "keep the webcam active"), stream these video frames *somewhere*, and then grab single video frames and convert them to an image on demand. However, I do not know how to do this (and if there is a better way).

EDIT: I need a one-off command that writes the image to stdout, so I can use it in a http server to serve a http GET request. It needs to be quick, because taking the picture is blocking a mechanical process in a machine.

Answer (score 5):

For my webcam, `fswebcam` takes a picture in less than half a second:

```
$ time fswebcam test1.jpg
...
real    0m0.491s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.000s
```

It takes a bit longer to write to stdout and then save it:

```
$ time fswebcam - > test2.jpg
...
real    0m0.538s
user    0m0.029s
sys     0m0.000s
```

You can also take images every *n* seconds (`--loop n`), if this is what you need (you didn't explain *why* you want it as fast as possible, and if or how a loop can help).

You can brighten the image, or adjust contrast etc. with the controls shown with `fswebcam --list-controls`.

Comment: For the "minimal delay" you can also send signal SIGUSR1 to fswebcam to have it capture immediately, when it is in timed loop mode.

Comment: Thank you dirkt and @meuh. I updated my question to explain why I need this. I see now that my webcam is simply slow when getting the first picture. I will see if using fswebcam with the loop option in combination with SIGUSR1 helps. I found another solution (I'll post it here), but it is also not optimal (it lowers the cameras fps).

Comment: Did you find a way to take pictures fast ?

Answer (score 1):

I found one possible solution myself, although it is not optimal, because on the Raspberry Pi where I want to implement this it reduces the FPS to half the value that the camera supports (and lower FPS = more possible delay until next video frame which can be extracted as picture).

I use ffmpeg to copy the video data from the hardware device at /dev/video0 to a [v4l2-loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) device at /dev/video1. This way the camera stays active becaues ffmpeg is reading from it at /dev/video0, while I can use another instance of ffmpeg to extract pictures from /dev/video1.

To install v4l2-loopback on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch):

1. Install kernel headers: `apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers` ([Re: How to install kernel-headers](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=154749#p1011982))
2. Install v4l2-loopback: `apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms` ([v4l2-loopback distributions](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback#distributions))
3. Add loopback device: `modprobe v4l2loopback` or with more devices `modprobe v4l2loopback devices=2` ([v4l2-loopback run](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback#run))

To copy the video from /dev/video0 to /dev/video1:

```
 ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format yuyv422 -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f video4linux2 /dev/video1
```

My camera supports the formats mjpeg and yuyv422, but only a "raw" format can be copied to the loopback device, so I must use yuyv422. The camera supports up to 6 fps with yuyv422 and 1920x1080, but the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B only manages to copy about 3 fps to the loopback device.

Now I can use the command I already mentioned in the question to extract the pictures, as JPEG:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format yuyv422 -i /dev/video1 -f image2 -frames:v 1 -qscale:v 2 pipe:1
```

Or as bitmap:

```
 ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format yuyv422 -i /dev/video1 -c:v bmp -f image2 -pix_fmt bgr24 -frames:v 1 pipe:1
```

With these command reading from the loopback device, the images are not dark and it takes about 1.3 seconds (JPEG) or 1.1 seconds (bitmap) to send them to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

The top voted answer takes 4~4.5 seconds for me, hanging on a syscall. Using `strace` I see that the delay comes from `ioctl(3, VIDIOC_STREAMON, [V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE]`.

The solution I found in order to be able to capture frames fast is to have a continuous stream using `streamer` (could probably also use `ffmpeg` or other tools) and process it in Python. Something like:

```
import os, subprocess
subprocess.DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')  # py3 polyfill

# Because the video is 320x240 and the format rgb (3 bytes, one for each color)
framesize = 320 * 240 * 3

proc = subprocess.Popen('streamer -r 2 -s 320x240 -f rgb -t 360'.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

buf = ''
while True:
    previousbufferlength = len(buf)
    buf += proc.stdout.read(framesize)
    if len(buf) == previousbufferlength:  # read() returned zero bytes: EOF
        break

    while len(buf) >= framesize:
        # Process the first $framesize bytes of the buffer here!
        # For example, write the frame to disk:
        f = open('your.rgb', 'w')
        f.write(buf[ : framesize])
        f.close()

        buf = buf[framesize : ]
```

This doesn't use `b''` and the like (bytes instead of string) because it is made to work with `pypy`. On a Raspberry Pi 2 v1.1, `pypy` can create basic stats of each pixel in the image while using less than 3% CPU -- granted, that is at 320x240 resolution and 2 frames per second, but that's all I need at the moment. The `streamer` process uses a similar amount.

To convert the rgb24 to another format, `ffmpeg` can help you out (for one frame or for a whole stream):

```
ffmpeg -r 2 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -s 320x240 -i your.rgb out.mkv
# For a picture format, just change the extension to jpg:
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -s 320x240 -i your.rgb out.jpg
# Or if you have more than one frame in your video, but you just want one frame:
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -s 320x240 -i your.rgb -vframes 1 out.jpg
```

OP's end goal is to make this yield instant pictures for a web server. To achieve that, you need to tie these parts together still, but I think above should be all the components you need if you have a webcam like mine.

Mind that many webcams need a few seconds to focus, adjust white balance, and perhaps do other things. Even if `fswebcam` works for you in <0.5s, it might yield much better picture quality to instead take frames from a stream and serve those rather than spawning a new capture stream on the webcam for the duration of a single frame. A setup like this, where the Python code above serves the latest frame at will to a client, would also scale much better than starting a process per visitor per page load which won't work concurrently.

And if we're on the topic of serving from streams, another tip I can give is using something like HLS or DASH. `ffmpeg` can, once again, help here and output a HLS format that you can cut up arbitrarily yet still view it.